# Zweihander or Greatsword?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There is a lot of dispute among some people as to which one is actually better, and for all my research, I haven't come to any conclusions.

Assuming 50 STR and 50 DEX, +10 with no imbuing, which one is better and why?

Comment: please define 'better'.  Are you concerned about PVE or PVP?

Comment: Neither really. Just in general terms. If there is a major difference, I would prefer PvE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the wikia. 
The greatsword gets S rank strength scaling at +10, the Zweihander maintains a B rank strength scaling.
http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Greatsword http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Zweihander

At a high level, the Greatsword would be better.

Also, the Greatsword's base damage is 400 vs the Zweihander's 360. Greatsword is an all around better damage dealer.

Answer (score 0):

The Greatsword should do more damage with the stats you have. since it has better scaling.

Comment: Proof! Numbers! Specifics! Links!

Answer (score -3):

well stat wise, greatsword is better but the zweihander is better  for me because it weighs a lot less so i can use it with whatever armour i have on at the point

Comment: You didn't stat any real fact, only opinion (not much can do with this kind of question...)